# Write a java program that reads a list from a List.txt file and the program should output the sorted array to SortedList.txt file

Tags: java

The following code compiles but it it is giving me an error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
>       \Users\name\Documents\HeapProject\Employee.txt (No such file or 
>       directory)
>       at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>       at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:196)
>       at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:139)
>       at java.base/java.util.Scanner.(Scanner.java:611)
>       at EmployeeDemo.main(EmployeeDemo.java:18)
>    ----jGRASP wedge: exit code for process is 1.
>    ----jGRASP: operation complete.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class EmployeeDemo
{
   public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException 
   {
    //list of employees in the file 
      Employee[] list = new Employee[5];
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter the text file: ");
      String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
    //read the file from the same folder
      File myFile = new File(fileName);
      Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);

      String id = inputFile.nextLine();
      String name = inputFile.nextLine();
      double salary = inputFile.nextDouble();
      String department = inputFile.nextLine();
      String position = inputFile.nextLine();
      int yearsOfService = inputFile.nextInt();
  //there are 6 items for all 5 employees
      list[0] = new Employee(id, name, salary, department, position, 
      yearsOfService);

      System.out.println("Enter the sorted text file: ");
      //String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
      PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("outputFile.txt");

      HeapSort.heapSort(list);

      while(inputFile.hasNext())
      {
         outputFile.println(list[0].toString());
      }

      outputFile.close();
      inputFile.close();
      System.out.print("File is sorted into the sorted file");
   }
}

the output should print the data from the file to the sorted file.
```

Comment: you'll probably need to use the absolute file path in order to open the file

Comment: are you passing `fileName` with file extension?

Comment: yes! after this, your program asks you to type the file path, are you passing it with proper file extension.(if the file is in the same folder)

Comment: the output asks to input the file name so that it can read and transfer to another file which is supposed to be sorted file using the data from the first file. However, I get an error when i enter the file name.

Comment: the file and the sorted file is in the same folder as the demo program

Comment: When you write the full path, do you include \\ to escape the slash? "C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\FileName.txt" ?

Comment: Yes I wrote it in the same exact way but I just don't why it's not working

Comment: As the previous comments above state...path and extension are needed but  there should be some validation first that the file exists in case the user mistypes something

Answer (score 0):

1st:

Check that, if there is Employee.txt in \Users\name\Documents\HeapProject\
And be sure that, you do not enter any space or something like that after .txt

Your input should be exactly "Employee.txt", not "Employee" and your input files name should be exactly "Employee.txt".

2nd: 
you can try that:

import these;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
```

Then, try this:

```
FileReader fReader = new FileReader(inputFile);
BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(fReader);

String id = bReader.readLine();
String name = bReader.readLine();
double salary = Double.parseDouble(bReader.readLine());
String department = bReader.readLine();
String position = bReader.readLine();
int yearsOfService = Integer.parseInt(bReader.readLine());
```